# What's the relationship between charge and acidity/basicity?

Tags: acid-base

I understand the acidity of a substance increases with electronegativity and size (valence shell space) of an atom (periodic trend) that contains a hydrogen atom (Brønsted-Lowry). However when looking at following pairs, I am not able to determine which one is a stronger acid.

$$\ce{H3O+ ,\ H2O}$$

Further, I would want to reason, the relationship between the charge and acidity/ basicity.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1341/is-this-the-correct-relative-bronsted-acidity-in-these-four-acids

Comment: @Mithoron, you may mark my question as a duplicate in that case. Spot on. I guess I panic and question. Instead I should do more research.

Comment: Hmm, it seems there's answer to your q. so maybe... Also http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24342/what-is-the-ka-of-oh-and-kb-of-h3o is related